# Which way to use to convert an image read with cv2 to bytes? tostring() or io.BytesIO?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to convert an array `A` to bytes, there are two ways:

```
img_file = "/home/test.jpg"
A = cv2.imread(img_file)
im_bytes = A.tostring()
```

or

```
img_file = "/home/test.jpg"
A = cv2.imread(img_file)
_, JPEG = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', A)
```

I do not understand their differences. And the result of `A.tostring()` will get less memory. Can anyone can explain it?

Comment: Is `im_bytes` the same in both examples and you want to know which way is preferred, or is `im_bytes` different in the two examples and you want to know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
import cv2

A = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
im_bytes = A.tostring()
```

`A` will be a Numpy array of all the pixels in the image. So if the image is 1024x1024 and RGB, `A` will be a Numpy array of `shape(1024,1024,3)` which directly contains all the RGB pixels in an array of type `np.uint8`. Then, when you run `tobytes()/tostring()` on it, it will have a size of 3MB, of raw pixel data with no dimensions, no date, no compression. If you transmit it to someone else on a socket, or save it in a file, the receiver will not know if it is 1024x1024 RGB, or 1048576x3 greyscale, or 384x2048 RGBA.

On the other hand, when you do this:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import io

A = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
pil_im = Image.fromarray(A)
b = io.BytesIO()
pil_im.save(b, 'jpeg')
```

`b` will now be a lossily JPEG-compressed version of your image that contains the same as if you had written it to a JPEG file. So it contains the date you wrote it, the image dimensions, the colourspace and the tables needed to decompress it as well as the compressed pixel data. `b` is essentially a JPEG in RAM.

---

There are further issues with your second example.

Firstly, and most importantly, there is absolutely no point decompressing a JPEG image into a Numpy pixel array and then recompressing it into a JPEG. If you want JPEG-encoded data, you might as well read it undecoded straight from the file:

```
with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as f: 
    image = f.read()
```

Secondly, if for some unknown reason you really do want to decode the JPEG into a Numpy array of raw pixels and then re-encode it back to JPEG, you might as well use OpenCV rather than introduce a whole new dependency on PIL:

```
A = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
_, JPEG = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', A)
```

Thirdly, if you insist on needlessly decoding and re-encoding to JPEG, and also on introducing PIL as a dependency, you will get yet another problem. Since you read the image with OpenCV you will get it in BGR order. PIL stores images in RGB order. So, if you make a PIL Image from the OpenCV Numpy array, you wlll get the red and blue channels swapped and all your colours will be wrong.

Comment: thanks. I understand it.  As you suggest, I have modified my question.